# SharePoint email notification workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, notifications

I created SharePoint email notification workflow for a LIST but it does not send emails. When I make changes to the list, the workflow complete but does not send an email notification.

What changes should I do so that the on-premise SharePoint can send email notification?

Comment: check this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13771.sharepoint-troubleshooting-alert-email-does-not-go-out.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First remove the workflow from the SharePoint and Do the following Procedure:

1-Close SPD if it is open

2-Open My Computer

a. Click the address bar

3-Paste in:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

4-Delete everything within this location

5-Click the address bar

6-Paste in:
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

7-Delete everything in this location

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following cases

1. The workflow shouldn`t run with system account.
2. The email recipient must be a valid user in SharePoint. (Add log statement before and after email action to make sure Workflow passing your logic).
3. Check your SMTP settings if you are using SharePoint on premises. (Add a small alert any SharePoint to see emails are working on SharePoint farm.)

Will further assist based on your validations.

Comment: 1. I am not using system account, The email recipient is a valid sharepoint user, The third is the one am not sure about, how can I check if the SMTP settings are correct.

Comment: On a SharePoint list create an alert to that user. You can refer this article http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-alerts/

Comment: Hey Venkat, It seems the workflow is running with system account, I just checked the USER ID and it's SYSTEM ACCOUNT. How can I resolve this...thank you

Comment: You should not run a workflow with system account that is a basic rule. Can you insert or update an item into a list with a user account?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your workflow runs when an Item is modified. Usually when you setup a workflow it only runs when an Item is created. change the configuration to make sure it runs when an Item is modified. Also add a log statement before and after the step when you send email. Display the email recipient name/email in the Log statement to make sure you have a valid email address.